# How to choose a framework in selenium?

Tags: selenium, java

I want to automate a web application. I am using selenium. But I am confused about how to select a framework. 
Selenium framework : 
1.Keyword driven framework, 
2.Data driven framework, 
3.Hybrid framework and also page object design pattern. 
Which framework do I need to select?
which one is best for automating a web application ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say say a framework I normally associate that, in Selenium, with meaning pick a language and test framework.  Is that what you mean?

The choices there are basically Java, C#, Python and Ruby.

I am a Ruby guy so I know that next when you pick a test framework you are talking RSpec or TestUnit.  Similar framework exist for other languages.  The actual integration with the browser is done using Capybara.

The usual criteria then is whatever language your organization has most skills in and is most comfortable with using.  If you need to hire folks the skills available in the local market may be a factor too.

As for using page objects that is a good practice regardless of language and Framework and the implementation of Page Objects which I have seen as static methods, dynamic methods, hash values variables, .yml files, etc.  The implementation isn't important is the abstraction into meaningful and DRY names that remove the element identifiers from the test code.